# testng.xml parallel test sequence

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, testng

For the given testng XML:

```
<suite name="Automation Suite" allow-return-values="true" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Installer 01">
        <parameter name="DB" value="Oracle"/>
        <parameter name="App_Server" value="WebLogic"/>
    </test>
    <test name="Installer 02">
        <parameter name="DB" value="Oracle"/>
        <parameter name="App_Server" value="WildFly"/>
    </test>
    <test name="Installer 03">
        <parameter name="DB" value="Oracle"/>
        <parameter name="App_Server" value="TomCat"/>
    </test>
    <test name="Installer 04">
        <parameter name="DB" value="MySql"/>
        <parameter name="App_Server" value="WebLogic"/>
    </test>
    <test name="Installer 05">
        <parameter name="DB" value="MySql"/>
        <parameter name="App_Server" value="WildFly"/>
    </test>
    <test name="Installer 06">
        <parameter name="DB" value="MySql"/>
        <parameter name="App_Server" value="TomCat"/>
    </test>
</suite>
```

How can I execute lets say Installer 01 & Installer 04 and wait for them to finish until i run the next permutation of Installer 02 & Installer 05 and so on.